# Are there any tools to do change management with Active Directory / Group Policy?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

We seem to be having a lot of problems related to "forgetting some mundane detail" while managing our Group Policy settings in Active Directory, so I am curious as to whether there are any well-regarded tools available for applying source control style practices to Active Directory configurations.

It seems like there should be a way to quickly and easily run a diff against a known-good configuration to figure out what setting changed (or did not replicate to a remote server) and is thus causing problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Microsoft Advanced Group Policy Management](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/enterprise/products/advanced-group-policy-management.aspx) which offers GPO change management.  It's a pretty good tool that they bought from Policymaker a few years ago.

Comment: +1 This is becoming the officially supported solution for this situation.  It does cost extra though I think.

Comment: Thanks!  This looks like exactly what we need to be using.  I only wish the licensing / purchase options weren't so darn confusing.

Comment: AGPM is very nice. It takes dedication because you cannot enforce its usage (thus domain admins have to play the game), but it's a very nice addition if you want to have serious change control in place. It's often overlooked and seen as a concept useful only to developers, but it's really worth it for group policies. If I'm not mistaken, it's part of the MDOP suite that is 'free' if you have a software assurance

Answer (score 0):

[NetIQ Change Guardian for Active Directory](http://www.netiq.com/products/cgad/default.asp)

I know nothing about it. Years ago we evaluated it( probably its predecessor) but never actually use it.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box there is no undo (although ntdsutil allows some recovering of deleted objects with an authoritative restore), or version control on AD. There are quite a few [third party tools](http://www.quest.com/object-restore-for-active-directory/) that will allow "undelete".